# How to compile dansguardian

Tags: linux, installation, centos7

I am trying to download `dansguardian` on centos 7 but I am not able to do so. Please anybody can help for this.

I have downloaded tar.bz2 file of `dansguardian` and then performed these step

```
tar -xjvf taf_file
./configure
make
```

> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

```
make install
```

Comment: you can download the dansguardian RPM file if you cannot compile it

Comment: What is the output of `./configure` ?

Answer (score 0):

Trying install all development tools like this:

```
      yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

then run:

```
./configure
make 
make install
```